# Error in receiving mail by action mailer in rails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am unable to receive the mail by Action Mailer in production.
I am using the same configuration in development & production mode .I can receive the mails in development but not in production.
The logs displayed that the mail is sent to the particular mail id but I can't receive that mail .I can receive few mails after 1 day .
Below is my configuration in production.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # Set the application URL which is used in the mail
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://abcd.com', port: '80' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "webmail.xxx.com",
      :port => 25,
      :domain => "mydomain.com",
      :authentication => :login,
      :user_name => 'xxxx',
      :password => 'xxxx',
      :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
  }
```

If I use the gmail configuration instead of above, then it works fine & I can receive the mails.

Comment: So that means the config for smtp_settings is incorrect, which mail service are you using? SendGrid?

Comment: I am using roundcube. When I send a reset password mail , it works but in other cases it doesn't works.

Comment: Hmm it is weird, I think you may check out the log to see what happened!